# MongoDB indexes issue

Tags: mongodb, indexing

MongoDB can store documents with different fields in one collection.
How then indexes will work? If I create index on field that presents not in all documents,  the documents which don't have that will not be indexed?

Answer (score 1):

Documents without the field in an index will be indexed as having no value for that field. You probably want to review this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/

If you want to not include documents that don't have the key in the index, you can use a sparse index: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/indexes/#sparse-indexes

Comment: Thank you! One more question :) What if I have for example 10 possible attributesand each document in collection have 2 or 3 of this attributes only. And I want to search this collection by any of possible 10 attributes or by any combination of them. Is it possible to create index for this purpose in mongo?

Comment: Sure. You can put a compound index on all of the fields, although this is probably not the best. I hope you aren't trying to do range queries, though, because that will give you some grief (performance-wise). Also, you should really test your index out with some sample data. Sometimes it's faster to have a single index on all of the fields, and sometimes a compound index is faster. It can be hard to create a general purpose index for all queries, and it can be inefficient (space-wise) to create indexes for every combination of fields you want to query on (which would probably be faster).

Comment: Thanks :) How would mongo behave in such case: document has two fields, for example, title and author. I create index only for title. And I will search by both attributes. Index will not be used?

Comment: It has a query optimizer that checks whether it should use the index. It will likely use it for that query (and then scan documents via the index for the author attribute), but you never know.

Comment: I posted about testing queries in mongodb a while back: http://wes.skeweredrook.com/testing-with-mongodb-part-1/